# XPath select attribute within a HTML tag

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, xpath, xpath-2.0

I have a  HTML tag which looks like this:

```
<li>
<img class="myClass" src="someURL" />
</li>
```

I'm trying to extract the img src value using XPath, however I'm not quite sure how to do this.

I have tried something like this, after selecting the li element:

```
"//img[contains(@class,'myClass')]@src"
```

However this didn't work :/

Can someone help me out with this ?

Comment: Anyone guys ? =)

Answer (score 1):

```
//img[contains(@class,'myClass')]/@src

//(Anywhere in the document)
img(select all img node)
/(Selects from the root node)
@src(Select Attribute src)
```

Comment: One sec trying it out =)

Comment: I keep getting empty string no matter what I do... what's going on here xD

Comment: Try 
//img[contains(@class,'myClass')]/./@src

Comment: you may have an other error has the xPath gives me a hit with the exemple you provided

Answer (score 1):

> after selecting the li element:

If the `<li>` element is selected, use this XPath:

```
img[contains(@class,'myClass')]/@src
```

Just one little `/` at the end.